# How to add details in seaborn pairplot

Tags: seaborn

I want to add pairwise correlation onto the pairplot but couldn't find a parameter to add the annotation, only a complicated method below. However, using this user-defined function, the r annotation seems overlapping. Not sure what caused this. How to fix this? Also is there a parameter to normalize input variables in pairplot? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Since you are using `hue=` the function is called once per hue-level (3x in your case, hence the overlap). Do you want the correlation coefficient for one of the hues, or all the hues combined?

Comment: @DizietAsahi Ah I see. Could u pls show code example for these two options?